# javascript event listener on focus-visable

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

I'm interested in creating an event listener for the "focus-visible" CSS selector. If a user is using an accessibility device or "tabbing" through the webpage, I want to use javascript to draw a box around what interactive element they will be engaging with when they press enter.

I tried doing something like this:

`document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("focus-visable", displayBox);`

but this of course didnt work as "focus-visible" is not a DOM event.

Comment: why not `focus`?

Comment: I do not want the rectangle drawn for users that only use the mouse. It's ugly and takes away from the UI experience. This feature is primarily for accessibility purposes.

Comment: use separate css file for mobile and tab device?

Comment: What do you mean by "tab device"? im talking about a normal google chrome browser. if a user wants to click the keyboard tab button through a list of items then i want javascript todraw boxes around the items as they press tab. If they directly interact with the list using the mouse then i do not need the box to be drawn. I want the CSS focus-visible functionality But i have 2 div tags side by side that work as a single button. When either one is clicked the same action happens. so I want it so that when you use "tab" key on keyboard over 1 div both divs have a single box drawn around them.

Comment: not sure if css media query works for you

Comment: You maybe have to sense keys being pressed and then test if there is an activeElement and if so highlight it as you want (and de-highlight it on any sort of click-focus).